# java:25: class, interface, or enum expected public static void main(String s[]) {

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I am trying to make a program to count words of a string.

The following is my code, and the errors coming in my code and I am unable to correct them:

```
import java.util.*;    
class string1 {
    public static int wordcount() {
        String str;
        Scanner s1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String:");
        str=s1.nextLine();
        int count=WCount(str);
        System.out.println("Count="+count);
    }

    public static int WCount(String str) {
        int l=str.length();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i)==' ')
                count++ ;
        }
        if(count>0) 
            count++ ;
        return(count);
    }
}
public static void main (String s[]) {
    string1 ss=new string1();
    ss.wordcount();
}
```

Error :

```
java:25: class, interface, or enum expected
public static void main(String s[]) {
          ^
C:\Users\coocl\Desktop\java\string1.java:27: class, interface, or enum expected
ss.wordcount();
^
C:\Users\coocl\Desktop\java\string1.java:28: class, interface, or enum expected}3 errors

Process completed.
```

Comment: Methods should be inside a Class, `main` should be inside (at the very least) inside the `string1` class you have there

Answer (score 5):

You main is out of the class. Declare it inside the class.

Comment: is main overloadable? is there overloading in java? Overloading can span out of class?

Comment: Obviously overloading is supported in Java. You can overload (not override) static main function. It can not be declared out of the class because even if it is a static function, it must belong to class and hence must be declared inside that class.

Comment: is this all about a linker thing? or is a must?

Answer (score 4):

The `main` method belongs *inside* your class. When you run `java` to execute your compiled code, it will try to run the `main` method that belongs to the class that you specify. More generally, methods **can't** be declared outside classes in java: all methods must belong to a class.

Note that since your methods `wordcount` and `WCount` are both static, you don't need to create a `string1` instance to use them, you can just call them on the class in `main` :

```
string1.wordcount();
```

Finally, in java, it is conventional to begin class names with uppercase, e.g. `String1`, see these [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` after WCount.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method must be inside a class, not outside. You have two ways:

1. Move it inside your `string1` class.
2. Move it inside a class in the same *.java file

   ```
   public class Main {
       public static void main (String s[]) {
           string1 ss=new string1();
           ss.wordcount();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Bad practice:

```
string1 ss=new string1(); 
ss.wordcount();
```

First char in Java class name must be UPPER and  
First char in Java method and fields name must be LOWER case; 
All chars in JAVA constants (static final) name must be UPPER case; 
wordCount() = static method and create object (string1 ss=new string1()) is not true. 
Static fields and methods need call from class name (not instance class).  
ClassName.(method/field) 
Must be String1.wordCount()

Your code have multiple problem (in "{}", "return" in wordcount())
See code:

```
public class Test {
    public static int wordcount() {
        String str;
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String:");
        str = s1.nextLine();
        int count = WCount(str);
        System.out.println("Count=" + count);
        return count;
    }

    public static int WCount(String str) {
        int l = str.length();
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ')
                count++;
        }
        if (count > 0)
            count++;
        return (count);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
                Test.wordcount();
    }
}
```